# My simple python program does not execute the last line

Tags: python, firefox-addon, stdin

I have a simple Firefox extension, I have pretty much figured out the Firefox side of things (JavaScript, DOM and starting the Python program).

To explain how everything is supposed to work:

1. A event occurs in the browser
2. Firefox launches the Python program on the local system (achieved with [Native Messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging))
3. Firefox passes a one time message to the Python program via stdin

After step 3, Firefox is meant to exit the picture and Python is supposed to take over.

I am stuck on the Python part of this process. The python program does receive the message from Firefox, via stdin. But once execution goes past the line `receivedMessage = getMessage()`, I start to get odd behaviour. For example the last line `subprocess.Popen(...` is never executed. Even if I were to launch the Python program manually, say double clicking it in File explorer, the last line never executes.

The only way to make it execute is by commenting out `receivedMessage = getMessage()`.

```
import subprocess
import json
import struct
import sys

def getMessage():
    rawLength = sys.stdin.buffer.read(4)
    messageLength = struct.unpack('@I', rawLength)[0]
    message = sys.stdin.buffer.read(messageLength).decode('utf-8')
    return json.loads(message)

receivedMessage = getMessage()
#subprocess.Popen(["explorer", "C:/Temp"])            #Is never executed
subprocess.Popen(['pwsh', 'C:/Temp/testProg.ps1'])   #Is never executed
```

The core of the program is an example I got from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging#app_side) page, that I reworked by getting rid of the redundant parts. I don't know the technical details behind stdin and how its specifically implemented in Python, I understand it at a high level only.

What could be holding back the execution of the program? Could it be held up by Firefox still streaming data to it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe you are getting less data than you are trying to read and you are blocked in the read() call.  put out a message before and after the line with read(messageLength) and see if you get the messages, one message or none.

Comment: Yeah, the problem must be that one of the `sys.stdin.buffer.read()` calls doesn't have enough to read, and so it just waits forever.

Comment: @LhasaDad, Is there a way to force the python program to show a console window for debugging purposes? Currently as it is, I cant  print any messages as I have not interface to read it or observe it from. The only choice I have is to bring the function that responds back to the browser console. Which I know for sure receives input from std and responds back after.

Comment: @Ralf_Reddings How is the python program currently being launched?   you might want to bring up the devtools for the browser and go to the console tab and see if print statements from your python show up there.   tough to tell without the context of how the python is being launched.