# stdin is not being saved to file

Tags: python, stdin

I am trying to get a better understanding how stdin works and how to specifically work with it in Python.

I am trying to save whatever is received from stdin to a file. The file should have two lines

- Line one should be the letter count of the string
- Line two should be the string itself

```
rawLength = sys.stdin.buffer.read(12)
file = open("my_file.txt", "w") 
file.write(len(rawLength) + "\n" + rawLength)       #file.write(rawLength)  <== Does not work either
file.close
```

The file does get created but nothing happens to it. it is empty and remains empty after the python program exits.

I tried this, sure enough the console does print it as shown [HERE](https://i.imgur.com/yP7giFR.png)

```
import time

rawLength = sys.stdin.buffer.read(12)    #save std to var
time.sleep(3)                            #because console window closes too fast
print(len(rawLength))
print(rawLength)
time.sleep(44)
```

The point of this exercise is to increase my understanding of std, so I can solve [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77463403/my-simple-python-program-does-not-execute-the-last-line?noredirect=1#comment136564351_77463403) problem that I asked about yesterday

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `file.close` needs to be `file.close()`. IIRC, stuff can get stuck in buffers if you don't flush them or close the file.

Comment: Your code cannot possibly work. `len(rawLength) + "\n"` will fail because `len` returns an integer.  Show us the exact code you're using that doesn't work.

Comment: Prefer to use a `with` context manager [when writing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-files) to a file, to ensure it closes nicely.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, and sure enough that is what I have been experiencing, I will look into this flush thing you mention. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some others have stated, the code you provided on its own does not work for a few reasons:

- You forget to import `sys`
- You try to use the `+` operator with an integer (the length) and a string
- You forget the parentheses when calling `file.close()`

After fixing those errors, I was able to run this successfully with Python 3.10. This almost produces the desired output, with some caveats.

```py
import sys

rawLength = sys.stdin.buffer.read(12)

file = open("my_file.txt", "w")

file.write(f"{len(rawLength)}\n{rawLength}")
file.close()
```

By providing `12` to the `sys.stdin.buffer.read` function, you are limiting the amount of data you can read to 12 bytes. This means if you provide more than 12 bytes of data, the rest is lost. This also means if you provide less than 12 bytes of data, the program will sit waiting for more data before writing to the file.

File output after providing the string "This is an example" to `stdin`:

```
12
b'This is an e'
```

Note: `sys.stdin.buffer.read` provides the data as raw `bytes` instead of a `str` hence why `b'...'` is written to the file.

Comment: I get it now! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Your basic philosophy is fine, but the details are flawed.  Notice this slight rewrite, using `print` instead of `file.write`.  Your write call could not work, because you have mixed an integer, a Unicode string, and a bytes string.  This works:

```
import sys
rawLength = sys.stdin.buffer.read(12)
file = open("my_file.txt", "w") 
print(len(rawLength), file=file)
print(rawLength.decode(), file=file)
file.close()
```

Output:

```
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ python x.py
asdfhlaksjdf
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ cat my_file.txt 
12
asdfhlaksjdf
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$
```

As a general rule, that's not how you use `stdin` in a Python program.  `stdin` tends to be text, so we use `sys.stdin.readline`, or `for line in sys.stdin:`, or the `fileinput` module.

Comment: This is a very interesting way to aproach this for sure, Thank you for providing this!